# Can you ﬁnd a set $A$ which satisﬁes $A = \{2,|A|\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Can you ﬁnd a set $A$ which satisﬁes $A = \{2,|A|\}$? Justify your answer.

Comment: @DietrichBurde : Not so. In that case, $A=\{2\}$ so $|A|=1$, which gives also that $A=\{2,1\}$ -- contradiction.

Comment: Why do you tag "measurable sets?"

Comment: @MPW I see, this is called [multiset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223405/can-elements-in-a-set-be-duplicated), if an element is contained twice.

Comment: @DietrichBurde : Yes, that allows repeated occurrences of an element. You could also use an *ordered* set, such as $(2,2)$.

Comment: I think if one allows multisets, then one needs to specify that.  Otherwise, sets do not have multiple elements, although the may be represented with individual elements presented mulitple times (but  actually only be one elements). Example: $\{c,o,n,s,t,r,u,c,t,i,o,n\} = \{c,i,n,o,r,s,t,u\}$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

3)If we do not allow multisets and do not allow sloppy notation, then whenever we have $M = \{x,y\}$ we know that $x \ne y$ and $|M| = 2$.

So if $A = \{2,|A|\}$ we know that $|A|\ne 2$ and $|A| = 2$.  Which is a contradictions.  So no such set exists.

I do not think this should be the answer because I believe $A= \{2,2\} =\{2\}$ and $|A|=1$ should be legitimate things to write.

.....

2)If we do not allow multisets (which we shouldn't) but allow sloppy notation (which in my opinion we should) and allow multiple representation of a single element-- for example; if  $K=\{x^2\% 10|x\in \mathbb Z\}$ then $K=\{... (-3)^2\%10, (-2)^2\%10, (-1)^2\%10,0^2\%10, 1^2\%10, 2^2\%10, 3^2\%10, ....\} = \{..... 9,4,1,0,1,4,9,6,5,6,9,4,1,0,..\} = \{0,1,4,5,6,9\}$ and $|K|=6$..or for example $M=\{$letters in the work "construction"$\}=\{c,o,n,s,t,r,u,c,t,i,o,n\}=\{c,o,n,s,t,r,u,i\}$ and $|M|=8$---

Then if $M= \{x,y\}$ then $|M| = 2$ if $x \ne y$ and $|M| = 1$ if $x=y$.

So if $A= \{2,|A|\}$ we would have $|A| =1$ if $|A| = 2$ or we would have $|A|=2$ if $|A|\ne 2$.  Both are contradictions and no such set can exists.

In my opinion this should be the answer.

......

1) If we allow the word "set" to include "multisets" (which in my opinion we should not),

then $|\{2,2\}| = 2$.  And also $|\{x,y|\}|= 2$ regardless as to whether $x=y$ or $x \ne y$.  So if $A = \{2,|A|\}$ then $|A| = 2$ and thus we have $A = \{2,|A|\} = \{2,2\}$.

[Ordered sets are a form of multisets, so the $A= (2,2)$, the ordered pair, will also by such that $|(x,y)| = 2$ so $A=(2,2) = (2,|A|)$, will work]

In my opinion, these should not be the answers as "multisets" are not sets, and sets can not have multiple representations of elements.  The set $\{2, |A|\}$, in my opinion, can be a set with two different elements, or a set with one distinct element that can be represent by being  written twice.  I think if you allow multisets and consider that a set with one element written twice, or in a distinct order to be a different object than a set with the one element written once, you are obligated to specify that.

.....

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** Note that as written, your set could have either one or two distinct elements, depending on whether $2$ and $|A|$ are equal or not. Try considering these cases separately.

Comment: Why on earth was this downvoted?! This is exactly the logic you must use to determine whether such a set can exist!

Comment: sorry for that. I've badly held down the wrong button. Sorry again.

Comment: @Matteo : I was really wondering. I understand now

Answer (score -2):

If $A=2$, then $A=\{2\}$, a contradiction.

If $A\neq 2$, then $|A| = 2$, which means that in fact $A=\{2\}$ and so $|A|=1$, another contradiction.