# Can a median value occur twice?

Tags: statistics, median

From a practice exam:

> From the set $$\{7, 12, 5, 16, 23, 44, 18, 9, Z\},$$ which of the following values $Z$ be equal to if it is the median of the set?
>
> Choose from: $14,  11, 12,  17, 21.$

$14$ was given as the correct answer.

But, arranging the numbers in increasing order with $Z = 12$ gives $$5, 7, 9, 12, 12, 16, 18, 23, 44,$$ in which case the median is $12,$ no?

Comment: Sets don't have repeated elements. If you put $Z=12$ the set would have $8$ elements

Comment: 1. A= {1,2,3,4} and B={1,1,2,3,4} [are valid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223405/can-elements-in-a-set-be-duplicated#comment8821550_223506), identical sets, since the duplicate elements of a set [are simply not counted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934378/why-cant-a-set-have-two-elements-of-the-same-value#comment1928373_934378).

Comment: 2. The median of a *set* (as opposed to a list) is not well-defined, so this question is stupid. $\quad$ That said, either (I) Z is indeed a duplicate element (this is technically allowed, as explained in #1), in which case your argument is correct, and both 12 and 14 are correct answers, or (II) Z is distinct from the other elements, in which case only the only correct answer is 14.

Answer (score 1):

The wording would have been "from the list" then $12$ would be possible, but "set" appears explicitly so elements have to be considered unique (set with repeated elements are called multisets).

Note also that when a set has an even number of elements, then we generally consider that the median is the average of the two central elements.

So would $Z=12$ then the set would in fact be $\{5,7,9,12,16,18,23,44\}$ and the median would actually be $(12+16)/2=14$ not $Z$.